# Interactive table of contents in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I wish I was able to recreate this small menu from the material ui website in my app :

[image: Screenshot from the material ui doc]

By now I have a component with a list and links :

```
import { Link, List, ListItem } from '@material-ui/core';

const burgerRecipe = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: "bread",
    quantity: 2
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "steak",
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "cheddar",
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "pickles",
    quantity: 2
  }
]
/**
 * MenuInteractiveColumn : 
 * @description 
 */
const MenuInteractiveColumn = props => {
  return (
    <>
      <List>
        {burgerRecipe.map(value => {
          return (
            <ListItem key={value.id}>
              <Link href={`/reservations#${value.name}`}
                underline="none"
                onClick={() => {
                  console.info("bip bop");
                }}
              >
                {value.name}
              </Link>
            </ListItem>
          )
        })}
      </List>
      <List>
        {burgerRecipe.map(value => {
          return (
            <div id={value.name}>
              {value.name} -------------


              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in lectus sit amet est mollis pharetra nec non augue. Phasellus eleifend ac erat non aliquam. Donec varius vel orci vel tempus. Suspendisse non dolor est. Duis at consequat diam. Etiam at bibendum orci, at tincidunt nulla. Integer vel quam non urna malesuada auctor. Quisque feugiat ligula dolor, vitae consequat magna mattis nec. Nulla massa nisl, fringilla et felis nec, lobortis placerat lectus. Praesent eget vehicula nulla. Cras lobortis metus sed pellentesque maximus. Proin nisi diam, euismod sit amet lacinia in, fringilla eget dolor. Nunc molestie magna id varius facilisis. Pellentesque sit amet posuere justo. Nullam faucibus lectus at mauris efficitur, sit amet hendrerit massa auctor.

              Fusce a dapibus nibh, at dignissim nulla. Donec tempus ut justo eu volutpat. Pellentesque eget diam ipsum. Nullam vehicula lorem et rhoncus mattis. Duis arcu libero, consectetur a sodales eget, malesuada at purus. Integer a mattis eros. Etiam sagittis, lectus cursus commodo molestie, ante justo maximus diam, pellentesque hendrerit nibh est sed ex. Cras pharetra interdum sagittis. Nulla tincidunt scelerisque purus, eget varius ipsum venenatis porta. Etiam fermentum, diam vitae tempor tempus, quam diam iaculis eros, id fringilla sapien felis ut metus. Quisque et mi condimentum, semper justo ultrices, euismod metus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Cras posuere et nisl ac ultrices. Donec eu dolor tincidunt, maximus augue quis, suscipit metus. Praesent convallis ut metus vel eleifend.

              Sed eu dignissim urna. Quisque sit amet risus sollicitudin, lobortis purus nec, consequat justo. Vestibulum non mauris faucibus, maximus nulla eu, convallis augue. Aenean vel libero nec felis ullamcorper auctor. Mauris efficitur sed tellus eget semper. Etiam blandit et lectus ut lacinia. Suspendisse faucibus enim convallis, placerat eros vitae, ullamcorper mauris. Quisque quis quam vestibulum, mollis justo ac, pellentesque nisl. Nunc iaculis tortor sit amet ex tristique convallis sit amet sit amet augue. Nulla aliquam sit amet enim eget placerat. Ut quis ex tincidunt, dignissim ligula non, euismod mauris. Sed euismod faucibus massa, vel aliquam elit euismod in.

              Aliquam id sapien nibh. Sed eu tellus eros. Cras interdum magna quis arcu dignissim, eget posuere felis dictum. Donec dictum euismod lectus, nec ornare erat suscipit at. Fusce mi nibh, ullamcorper porttitor orci sit amet, placerat ultrices eros. Nam rutrum mauris sit amet magna iaculis aliquet. Sed venenatis urna in metus volutpat, id sagittis nulla tempor. Curabitur odio metus, porttitor sit amet urna ac, posuere rhoncus neque. Morbi tortor libero, dapibus vitae finibus rutrum, placerat quis leo. Vivamus nunc leo, vehicula vulputate cursus ac, placerat vitae ex. Nullam eu nisl purus. Curabitur vitae egestas turpis, quis volutpat felis. Quisque sit amet purus facilisis, posuere ante in, laoreet nisl. Pellentesque ornare dolor nec lectus porttitor, et venenatis orci auctor. Vestibulum ultrices id enim vel interdum. Ut non tortor placerat, consectetur sem at, viverra elit.

              Etiam non tellus in nisl facilisis pharetra. Vivamus porttitor justo at fringilla euismod. Nunc neque lacus, scelerisque sed pellentesque quis, ullamcorper nec leo. Nullam sed dolor metus. Vivamus aliquet at erat eu blandit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque mollis neque at eros feugiat, nec lacinia lorem finibus. In semper vel lacus eu porttitor. Curabitur mollis lectus ac purus pretium, non facilisis odio viverra. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque ultrices nulla et nisi placerat, non tempus nisl elementum. Sed dui dui, vestibulum posuere enim vitae, sollicitudin rhoncus metus.
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </List>
    </>
  )
};

export default MenuInteractiveColumn;
```

And I would like it to go to some div in my page like it does on the [material ui website](https://material-ui.com/api/link/)

EDIT : It kinda works now but it hides the top of the *lorem Ipsum* under my navbar

Comment: You need to implement hash navigation, but that requires an extra library, I will make an example based on your code

Comment: @Sabbin I change my href and I am going somewhere but I am a little bit to low part of the text is hidden under my navbar

Comment: https://github.com/rafrex/react-router-hash-link#readme Try to use this library for scrolling into divs from the router. Read their documentation it's pretty straight forward

Answer (score 2):

While i do not have the time to make an example based on your code here are some resources which might be interesting to you:

- [material-ui - AppTableOfContents](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/404c2ba16816f5c7ab7d8b2caf6bbc3d2218b820/docs/src/modules/components/AppTableOfContents.js)
- [react-scrollspy](https://github.com/makotot/react-scrollspy) - see [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-xu80m) on how this can be used with tabs
- [react-scroll-agent](https://github.com/manifoldco/react-scroll-agent)
- [Antd anchor](https://ant.design/components/anchor/)

see also [material-ui: issue 16359](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/16359) for more information

Comment: I am currently trying to follow the codepen example, I will keep this question updated. Thank you for those links