# How to create a Vertical NavBar in React - Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I found the right side context nav bar menu on the material ui demo page: https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/ quite appealing. I like both the appearance and behavior of the component.
However, I don't know what components and style should I use.

[image: This component with it's behavior]

I want to know what guidelines and components should I use.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/61209231/8062659